# magento 1.9 version Transactional Email template content size limit

Tags: magento-1.9

am using magento 1.9 version in that  I'm trying to create some newsletter emails using magentos transaction email system but I've run into situation where when I save the template it cuts off the email at a certain point. Because of the nature of coding everythin in tables and inline css the html is quite large and for one particular email length is 1800 lines and its getting cut off at around 1200 lines for example i say. So my question is: Is there a limit to the size of email templates and if so can it be changed??

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a limit. And the limit is setted by the column "Newsletter_text" from your "Newsletter_queue" table.
The limit is 65.535 characters because the attribute type is Text. You can set different types for extend the limit, like setting up the column as "Longtext" or "Mediumtext".
Longtext will be able to contain 4.294.967.295 characters, Mediumtext can have a limit of 16.777.215 characters. Depending on your needs, choice the correct type.
I didnt try it yet, but it should work like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  changing the field type from "text" to "longtext" is working.

Comment: Great! Consider this also for other purpose in the future, like products attributes lenght and so on.